# Touch hotspot UIView like UIButton's with "Shows touch on highlight"

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow, radial-gradients

What is the best way to create programatically a semi-transparent UIView, looking like this:

[image: "Shows touch on highlight" of UIBUtton]

Basically the image shows results of pressing an UIButton with "Shows touch on highlight" option turned on. But I need to create a **touch hotspot** feature, which I will move over the screen while follow a translate gesture.